# FullCalendar plugin 3.1.0 is not displayed correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, laravel, fullcalendar

When I execute the following code, the *FullCallendar* is not displayed correctly. The result I get is the following: 
[image]

According to the *FullCallendar* demo it should look like this:
[image]
The debug console doesn't display any errors. What am I doing wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  defaultDate: '2016-12-12',
  editable: true,
  eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
  events: [
   {
    title: 'All Day Event',
    start: '2016-12-01'
   },
   {
    title: 'Long Event',
    start: '2016-12-07',
    end: '2016-12-10'
   },
   {
    id: 999,
    title: 'Repeating Event',
    start: '2016-12-09T16:00:00'
   },
   {
    id: 999,
    title: 'Repeating Event',
    start: '2016-12-16T16:00:00'
   },
   {
    title: 'Conference',
    start: '2016-12-11',
    end: '2016-12-13'
   },
   {
    title: 'Meeting',
    start: '2016-12-12T10:30:00',
    end: '2016-12-12T12:30:00'
   },
   {
    title: 'Lunch',
    start: '2016-12-12T12:00:00'
   },
   {
    title: 'Meeting',
    start: '2016-12-12T14:30:00'
   },
   {
    title: 'Happy Hour',
    start: '2016-12-12T17:30:00'
   },
   {
    title: 'Dinner',
    start: '2016-12-12T20:00:00'
   },
   {
    title: 'Birthday Party',
    start: '2016-12-13T07:00:00'
   },
   {
    title: 'Click for Google',
    url: 'http://google.com/',
    start: '2016-12-28'
   }
  ]
    });
});
```

```css
body {
 margin: 40px 10px;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
}

#calendar {
 max-width: 900px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
</head>
 <body>
  <div id='calendar'></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Typo here "$(document).ready(funcntio() {' but it looks as thought the css files aren't being loaded. Try refreshing the page to see if the styling is applied.

Comment: Apparently the css and js are loading correctly. I have cleared the browser cache but I get the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just took a look at that stylesheet and noticed it has the word `print` in the URL.  I then looked at the code and the comment says it's for a printer friendly version.  Looking at your screenshot, I'd agree that's what it's doing.

I removed the `.print` from the URL and it looks like that one is the one you need.

```
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.css
```

Try removing the one for printers.